# Affine space vs. tangent spaces on manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm trying to find a rigorous framework to think about Euclidean 'detached' displacement vectors vs 'glued' point vectors. I thought I had found such a framework with affine geometry: when working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can make this into an affine space by considering the translation action of the additive group of the associated vector space on itself. Under this interpretation, vectors glued at different points are actually the same vector; vectors are recovered as equivalence classes of displacements.

An interpretation which seems equally attractive, however, is to look at $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold and view the displacement vectors as elements of tangent spaces at different points. Under this interpretation, however, wouldn't displacement vectors be *different* from each other, because they are elements of different places? My confusion was compounded when I read about affine frames, which seem to offer a completely equivalent description to tangent spaces.

How should I look at these two frameworks? Are they equivalent?

Comment: The point with affine space is that there is a natural isomorphism between the tangent spaces of any two points, obtained by translating curves..

Comment: Affine space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ taken as a manifold with the action of translation group on it. Glued vectors live in tangent spaces attached to points, and free vectors live in the quotient of the product of two copies of the space (pairs of points) by the diagonal action of the translation group on it (pairs superimposable by a simultaneous translation are identified).

Comment: @Conifold so free vectors ARE distinct from glued vectors of tangent spaces (at points different from the origin), even though they may be represented identically? Which of the two is used in elementary physics, when representing Newtonian forces as vectors?

Comment: This is academic for $\mathbb{R}^n$ because you can pick a point in the space (origin) and canonically identify all tangent spaces and the diagonal quotient with the tangent space there, or the space itself. Forces are considered glued when acting on points, and partially free when acting on rigid bodies, see [Why is force a localized vector and not a free vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139824/65263)